# I am using `$().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser` to get the current user but it's not working for few users. Is that a browser issue?

Tags: spservices

I am using the following code... but its shows nothing for some users

```
var thisUserAccount = $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({
        fieldName: "Name",
        debug: false
      });
```

Comment: Please share the versions of the libraries being used.

Answer (score 2):

Its hard to tell what the issue is...

Have you looked around on the SPServices codeplex forums?

The thing with SPGetCurrentUser is that it scrapes a HTML page (`/_layouts/userdisp.aspx?Force=True`) for the information ([documentation here](https://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser&referringTitle=Documentation))... So if you go to that page for the given user(s) and you don't see the information you expect to retrieve, then the utility can't help you... The information on that page is expected to be in the format provided by a default OOB SharePoint installation, thus if you are working with a intance that has been heavily branded, things may look different from what this utility is looking for...

Answer (score 0):

Do those users have any value for name?

It's probably a better solution to get the Id, like this:

```
$().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({
    fieldName: "ID",
    debug: false
});
```